# Nginx redirects to other vhost when not entering https

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have a nginx installation with many vhosts.

Everything works fine except that when entering domains without ssl (http instead of https), they all redirect to https://DomainC.com.

For example, entering https://(www.)DomainA.com or https://(www.)DomainB.com work ok.

Entering http://(www.)DomainA.com or http://(www.)DomainB.com redirect to https://DomainC.com.

Notice that even entering a domain which i have installed to BIND DNS server but not assigned to any vhost on nginx, without https, it redirects to https://DomainC.com but when using https it properly shows my default vhost which is not any of the above domains.

vhosts contain these redirects:

```
if ($host = www.DomainA.com) {
    return 301 https://DomainA.com$request_uri;
} 
if ($host = http://DomainA.com) {
    return 301 https://DomainA.com$request_uri;
}
```

My nginx -T: https://pastefy.ga/XTSLoHKV

Comment: Do you think the $host variable can contain the scheme "http://" ?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I deleted this, added the below code, still same problem.
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name DomainA.com *.DomainA.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

Comment: Did you restart nginx? Did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: even restarted server..

Comment: Neither the lines in your original question nor those in your comment, are responsible for a redirect to domainC.  Better show us the lines that do contain domainC.

Comment: I did some changes regarging the http to https redirects, but still the same problem.
The nginx -T: https://pastefy.ga/XTSLoHKV

Comment: Please add the configuration to the question. External links often go bad.

Comment: i can't add the whole file, so i added the link

Comment: Hello, do you have any idea based on the nginx setup?